# How to fix iOS10 safe area and topLayoutGuide issue?

Tags: ios, swift, safearealayoutguide

I have a question about safe area.
And I write a code and build in two simulators of iOS version 10.2 and 11.4.
It shows different part of red rectangle area like following image.
What's wrong with me?
Thanks.

[image]

code here:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "TITLE HERE"

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.equalTo(10)
            make.top.equalTo(self.topLayoutGuide.snp.bottom)
            make.right.bottom.equalTo(-10)
        }

    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath) TEST"

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to apply top constraint 'relative To Margin'

Comment: Do you have example to me? Thanks.

Comment: Have you used any third party for applying constraint ?

Comment: @nikksindia I just use " Snapkit".

Comment: try this 'make.top.equalTo(view).inset(view.layoutMargins)'

Comment: why `make.right.bottom.equalTo(-10)` right.bottom?

Comment: @Scriptable I just want to have padding about UITableView.